# Passing PHP variable to Html link for modal and AJAX

Tags: php, html, cakephp, bootstrap-modal

In CakePHP 3, baked controllers have 4 functions that have their own views: Index, Add, Edit and Delete. I'm trying to move the Edit and View functions to modals, but I need the PHP variable to determine the specific data entry that is to be modified or viewed.

Eg. I have a table called Users.

In the Index function of the UsersController, I would define the following variable:

```
$users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

$this->set(compact('users'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
```

Then on the Index view (Index.ctp), inside the table I would have the following actions:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="actions">
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $user->id]) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want the above actions to pass $user->id into a HTML  tag that would open up a modal as follows:

View
Edit

And use JavaScript to open up the model.

```
$(function () {
   $('#view').click(function () {
        $('#viewModal').modal('show');
   });
});

$(function () {
   $('#edit').click(function () {
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
   });
});
```

Alternatively, just pass it straight to the modal, and then fetch data for each of the form fields based on that.

Then for the Edit modal, when saving, I would use AJAX PUT to save.

Edit Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
               </button>
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit</h4>
               <div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <?= $this->Form->input('firstname', ['class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'First Name', 'id' => 'firstname']); ?>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-6">
                       <?= $this->Form->input('lastname', ['class' => 'form-control', 'label' => 'Last Name', 'id' => 'lastname']); ?>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close
               </button>
               <button id="savebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes
               </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass an id to your link as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
<tr>
    <td class="actions">
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('View'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]), ['id' => 'view', 'data-id' => $user->id]) ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'view', $user->id]), ['id' => 'edit', 'data-id' => $user->id]) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

then within your modals define user id as follows:

*it isn't clear how do you implement your modals, so i will assume the following*

```
$(function () {
   $('#view').click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var userId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('#viewModal').modal('show');
   });
});

$(function () {
   $('#edit').click(function (ee) {
        ee.preventDefault();
        var userId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('#editModal').modal('show');
   });
});
```

you will need to pass the userid to your modal you using

Comment: On the View, I'm getting links as follows: `/project"name"`. Eg. for View, the link shows as `/projectEdit`. When I click the link, it takes me to that non existent directory (the actual directory is meant to be `/project/users/edit`), although I wanted to get it to open my modal instead. If I remove the nulls from the actions, the links use regular names, and the URL is as follows:

Comment: `/project/users/edit?id=view&data-id=2`. Again, the modal does not show up and it refreshes the page and sends me to the top.

Comment: It works for the first data entry, but not subsequent ones.

Comment: replace the id's by classes, use classes instead of ids

Comment: Sorry should say, the link now goes to the modal but only for the first data entry. In addition, the form inputs are not filled based on whatever the $user->id variable was.

Comment: When you say replace the ids, do you mean in the View/Edit links or the modal or both? And how would you go about replacing them with classes? I'm not sure which class. If I just replace id => 'view' in the link with class => 'view', then clicking the link won't produce a modal anymore.

Comment: the both, this ``'id' => 'view',`` should be as follows `'class' => 'view',` and `$('#view').click(function (ev) {` be `$('.view').click(function (ev) {` , `$('#viewModal').modal('show');` should be `$('.viewModal').modal('show');` and replace the viewModal id by class in your html

Comment: you also need to check out more about ids and classes in the DOM tree and the differences between it in javascript , this is important

Comment: That works (I didn't need to change the modal from id to class), now I can access the modal regardless of which data entry, although still the form inputs are not being filled in. Oh I also added in my modal code in the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138393/discussion-between-mistaq-and-hassan).