# TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get my Modal loading on click of a HTML  tag as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <table class="usersTables" id="userTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"><?= $this->Paginator->sort('name') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="actions"><?= __('Actions') ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= h($user->name) ?></td>                  
                <td class="actions">
                    <a href="#" id="managephoto">Manage Photo</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         $('#managephoto').click(function () {
              $('#myModal').modal('show');
         });
    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                 </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Photo</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 <button id="savebutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However I'm currently getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

This error only appears on the very first entry in the table, all the other identical links for other data entries do not show it (I believe the other links don't work at all as they should also give the same error).

I'm also getting sent straight back up to the top, though I suppose that's expected given that the HTML  tag has `href="#"`.

I've tried the following:

- Replace `$(function () {` with `$(document).ready(function () {`
- Replace `$(function () {` with `$(window).load(function () {`

Comment: Make sure you're only including **one** copy of jQuery

Comment: Also, you're potentially creating more than one element with `id="managephoto"`

Comment: As you can see [here (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/8fmdLozb/), it works correctly for the first link. The latter does not due to the ID duplication but it also does not trigger the error you're seeing. I suspect you're including a second instance of jQuery which resets the available plugins, removing `jQuery.fn.modal`

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful (and I did find one more jQuery script that I missed ) which now lets the first link load the modal. In another question I had, I wanted to pass PHP variables to a modal so that depending on which link I clicked, it would pass the appropriate ID. Eg. I click on the first link, I would Manage Photo of User with ID = 1, second link would led me Manage Photo of User with ID = 2 and so on. The answer I got in that question was to use data-id, though the answer is incomplete: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808723/passing-php-variable-to-html-link-for-modal-and-ajax

Comment: If you have another question, unrelated to the problem expressed above, please post it as a new question

Answer (score -1):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function () {
    $('#managephoto').click(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
  });
</script>
```

Try it, it's will work.